# knitr - strange behaviour summary(numeric) prints different values than str()

Tags: knitr, numeric, summary

I am trying to develop a reproducible research report that includes printed output of the variable distributions of input datasets.

I am confused by the result of summary() in the small example below.
When I evaluate the code directly to the console I get 'b' is all 2012 as expected, however when I run this with knit2html() it appears as 2010.

```
dat <- data.frame(a = letters, b = rep(2012, length(letters)))
str(dat)

## 'data.frame':    26 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ a: Factor w/ 26 levels &quot;a&quot;,&quot;b&quot;,&quot;c&quot;,&quot;d&quot;,..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
##  $ b: num  2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 ...

dd <- lapply(dat, summary)
dd

## $a
## a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
## 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
## 
## $b
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##    2010    2010    2010    2010    2010    2010

sessionInfo()

## R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## 
## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C           
##  [4] LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C       
##  [7] LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C        
## [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] knitr_1.5
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
## [1] evaluate_0.5.1 formatR_0.9    stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In knitr code chunks, `options("digits")` defaults to 4. The `summary` function has a `digits` argument that defaults to `max(3, getOption("digits")-3)` (see `?summary`). This causes `summary` to round 2012 to three significant digits, resulting in 2010.

You can either increase the `digits` option in your code chunk:

```
options(digits=7)
```

Or specify the `digits` argument in your call to `summary`:

```
dd <- lapply(dat, summary, digits=4)
```

Comment: thx, I want this to be generic so thinking of using `summary2 <- function(x){
  summa <- summary(x, digits = nchar(max(x))+3)
  return(summa)
}`